# Why is this loop not working, also how do I make the code remember the previous letters guessed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Im new to programming and was trying to program a word guesser. I dont understand why the while loop doesnt go though three times, also the program doesnt remember the previously guessed letters.

```
import random

words = ["hello", "bye", "petscop"]

GuessWord = random.choice(words)


tries = 3


while tries > 0:
    tries = tries - 1
    inp = input("\nEnter your guess: ")
    for char in GuessWord:
        if char in inp:
            print(char,  sep="",end="")
        elif char not in inp:
            print("_", sep="",end="")
            tries = tries - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have is that you decrease the number of tries by 2 each round. Therefore, at the beginning of the second round, the number of tries decreases again so it fails. This is how I would do it:

```python
import random
# library that we use in order to choose 
# on random words from a list of words
 
name = input("What is your name? ")
# Here the user is asked to enter the name first
 
print("Good Luck ! ", name)
 
words = ['rainbow', 'computer', 'science', 'programming', 
         'python', 'mathematics', 'player', 'condition', 
         'reverse', 'water', 'board'] 
 
# Function will choose one random
# word from this list of words
word = random.choice(words)
 
 
print("Guess the characters")
 
guesses = ''
 
# any number of turns can be used here
turns = 3
 
 
while turns > 0:
     
    # counts the number of times a user fails
    failed = 0
     
    # all characters from the input
    # word taking one at a time.
    for char in word: 
         
        # comparing that character with
        # the character in guesses
        if char in guesses: 
            print(char)
             
        else: 
            print("_")
             
            # for every failure 1 will be
            # incremented in failure
            failed += 1
             
 
    if failed == 0:
        # user will win the game if failure is 0
        # and 'You Win' will be given as output
        print("You Win") 
         
        # this print the correct word
        print("The word is: ", word) 
        break
     
    # if user has input the wrong alphabet then
    # it will ask user to enter another alphabet
    guess = input("guess a character:")
     
    # every input character will be stored in guesses 
    guesses += guess 
     
    # check input with the character in word
    if guess not in word:
         
        turns -= 1
         
        # if the character doesn’t match the word
        # then “Wrong” will be given as output 
        print("Wrong")
         
        # this will print the number of
        # turns left for the user
        print("You have", + turns, 'more guesses')
         
         
        if turns == 0:
            print("You Loose")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say, StackOverflow isn't a forum for debugging. StackOverflow is more about solving general problems that affect multiple people rather than single instances of a problem (like bugs), if that makes sense.

There is probably a better place for you to ask this question but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

In the spirit of being constructive: the following code appears twice and you should remove the second instance.

```
tries = tries - 1
```

Also, you are overwriting `inp` each time you enter the loop causing it to forget its previous value. There are other issues too. But that's a good start.